# Adding dynamic id in the url using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an edit page with url

```
example.com/product/edit/11
```

Now if the validation is false I intend to reload the edit page but can't figure how to add that id '11' in the url

Things I have done so far

In routes.php

```
$route['product/edit/(:num)'] = "product/edit/$1";
```

Now how do I pass that id in the url from the controller

I tried this

```
$this->load->view('product/edit/'.$edit_id,$data);
```

Edit: I am not trying to pass edit_id to the view file

I am trying to simulate this:

```
<a href="example.com/product/edit/11">Edit</a>
```

So that the function in my controller

```
function edit($edit_id)
{
//some code
}
```

Will have have that `$edit_id` to work with

It didn't work as I suspected.

I know I can pass that id to the view file and make it work, but I wanted to if I can pass that id in the url.

Thanks

Edit: I figured that even if I managed to pass it in the url. I will end up with more problem like setting the form attributes and other stuff. What I did was

```
redirect('product/edit/'.$edit_id);
```

and gave an error message by setting the `flashdata`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you pass the ID via $data from the controller, otherwise you'd be trying to call a non-existent view. (I'm not 100% sure though as I'm not a CI user)

Comment: Yeah I thought so  too, I am just wondering if there is some other way to do so. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry but, i dont understand you want to pass `edit_id` to your view ?

Comment: I just wrote that so as to show what I wanted. I don't want to pass edit_id to view, I can do that via $data as Ben suggested. What I would like is to pass that edit_id via the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Product.php` controller

```
function edit($edit_id) {

    //some codes

    //passing edit_id to view
    $data['edit_id'] = $edit_id;
    $this->load->view('product/edit', $data);
}
```

And in `view/product` folder, `edit.php` view file

```
 //some codes
 echo $edit_id
```

Or directly from url in view file

```
echo $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: This is now what I am after, this is how you would usually do in code igniter. What I am after is forcing something in the url from the controller.

Comment: i'm confused on whats wrong with safarovs answer, you can put the `$edit_id` into the `href="'<?=example.com/product/edit/'.$edit_id?>"` if the $edit_id is empty then `$this->uri->segment(3)` will just be blank

Comment: @timpeterson Yes you can put it in href my question however was if you can do something like that while loading the view file $this->load->view('product/edit/'.$edit_id) and it would result in that edit_id in the url which it won't as it would then try to find a non existent function, the href was just an example of what i wanted to achieve in the controller while loading the view file.

Comment: hi Kaushtuv, just assign $edit_id to an empty value if it doesn't exist, then it won't trigger an error. If this doesn't help, perhaps you can try re-explaining what your problem is? I'm still a little confused on what you are talking about though think there is a simple solution.

Comment: you can also add stuff dynamically to the url using JavaScript/jQuery like this: `$('a').attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+'/stuff to add to url');`